# Executing Mongo Inserts commands in text file using Mongo shell

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a text file which has mongo insert scripts.How can I execute the scripts to insert data into mongo collection using mongo shell rather than copying each single insert command pasting and executing in the shell.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `use mydatabase`, you have to prepend

```
db = db.getSiblingDB('<db>');
```

and the inserts should look like

```
db.mycollection.insert({....});
```

After this, you can do

```
mongo your.mongo.host yourInsertFile.js
```

In case you don't have a syntax error, it should do all the inserts.

See the docs about [scripting the mongo shell](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/) for details.

Answer (score 2):

Create a js file, your_script.js file.

```
 db = db.getSiblingDB('your_db_name');
 db.your_collection.insert({"name": "221 Baker Street"});
```

save the file. In mongo shell `pwd()` will give the current working directory.Move the js file to pwd location.
In mongo shell

```
load("your_script.js");
```

If your script dont have any error it will execute successfuly inserting the record into collection.